# Validating texbox control within gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, .net-4.0

I am developing an application where teacher are allowed to enter marks for students, based on selecting a subject they teach. Now I am using a 4 columed datagrid to which I am populating all the student rollnum(1st col) and name (2nd col) and textbox control to enter Test marks(3rd col) and textbox control to enter quiz marks(4th col). I have succeded in populating data to datagrid through datatable. Now my problem is, when teacher enters all the marks and click on submit button, I want my application to check if any of the textboxes are left empty. Unless and untill all the textboxes are filled, my INSERT query(Adding marks to database query) should not execute. This is what I have tried so far

```
int rowcount = DTUSNName.Rows.Count;//rows count of datatable
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        { 
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
                {
                    var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Once the marks are added you wont be allowed to make changes. Do you want to proceed?","Confirm!!",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        SqlCommand Test1query = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TblStudentReg (Test1, Quiz1) VALUES (@fld1,@fld2) WHERE Code=@code AND Sem = @sem AND CC=@cc AND AcademicYr = @aca", con);
                        Test1query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fld1", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                        Test1query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fld2", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
                        Test1query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", temp));//rollnum
                        Test1query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sem", StaffMEDrp1.SelectedItem));subject code
                        Test1query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cc", label3.Text));//subject code
                        Test1query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aca", StaffMETxt1.Text));//academic yr
                        con.Open();
                        Test1query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                     MessageBox.Show("You have not set Quiz 1 Marks for USN : '" + usn + "'");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have not set Test 1 Marks for USN : '" + usn + "'");
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: So is this generating any error/exception or doesn't recognize empty values and keeps on going ?

Comment: How about checking their `.Text` properties is null or empty string?

Comment: @Harvery : This is working fine. But I like to check if all the textbox control is not empty before going ti insert statement.

Comment: @Soner : I have done it and you can see it in my above posted code as well. But I need to make sure none of the textboxes are empty before executing insert statement

Comment: Do you have textBoxes or do you have `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`?

Comment: @Patrick: I am using DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to add a column within DataGrid

Comment: This look and feels terrible. Please separate the concerns and partition your code! create a function int checkCells() which does the looping and returns the number of errors. It also should set/reset the Backcolor to some reddish instead of pestering the user with messageboxes. if it returns 0 you can continue calling a save function.. - I wonder what you mean by making a difference between textBoxes and DataGridViewTextBoxCells : The formar always overlay the latter when in edit mode, you can't have one without the other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if what you have are DataGridViewTextBoxCells instead of TextBoxes you could use this method

```
static bool IsAnyCellEmpty(DataGridView gridView, params int[] columnIndexes)
        {
            bool result = false;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var index in columnIndexes)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[index].Value.ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                    {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

You should pass the column indexes of the validating columns in the second argument
if any of those are empty it will result as true

PS: if you want it to count how much values are not set you can change the result variable to `int` and do a `result++` instead of `result = true`

Comment: Patrick : I am using DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to add a column of textboxes. If adding a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn is a bad idea, please suggest me what I can use to replace DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.